# NoSuchElementException when submitting

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I'm a Comp Sci student and my university has a club for the ACM Programming competition. I've just started there and I am solving one of the problems. The program works perfectly when I run it and doesn't generate any exceptions. However, when I submit it on the site that runs tests and stuff it gives me:

An exception has occured in your application:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found  at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)    at Main.main(Main.java:16)

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner inMain = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    int q = inMain.nextInt();

    for (int j = 0; j < q; j++)
    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String temp = read.nextLine();
        a.add(temp);
    }

    int r = inMain.nextInt();

    for (int h = 0; h < r; h++)
    {
        int selection = inMain.nextInt();
        if (selection < 0 || selection > q)
        {
            System.out.println("Rule " + selection + ": No such rule");
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Rule " + selection + ": "
                    + a.get(selection - 1));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using one instance of scanner for system.in?

Comment: Did you type in something from the first `nextInt()`?

Comment: This is mostly because you are calling `nextInt` or `nextLine` when there is no token available. Try this code with multiple input files.

Comment: This is not a programming issue, just that the program expects a different input than what it is provided.

Comment: Yes what happens when I use one instance for the scanner is a different exception. It actually causes an InputMismatchException on line 20.

Comment: InputMismatchException is b/c you didn't pass in the right input, most likely you passed string instead of Int, make sure you understand what the program is doing before entering your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Check if next line exists before you access it

```
for (int j = 0; j < q; j++)
{
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (read.hasNextLine()){
        String temp = read.nextLine();
        a.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I added this and it fixed the problem, but now I am getting InputMismatchException in line 23 when submitting, but I don't get the error when I run on my machine.

Comment: Can you post the inputs?

Comment: I wish I could, I could probably solve it if I knew them. Unfortunately I don't have access to the unit tests it does on the code that is submitted for eval.